# Terraform - GCP - Get 'gateway_id' from google_compute_ha_vpn_gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm looking for a way to get the 'gateway' ID of a gateway, in terraform from GCP.

The gateway ID is a interger that appears to be created as part of creating a VPN Gateway, and shows up in the monitoring metrics as a field you can filter for your monitoring.
As we have multiple VPN gateways, I want to setup a separate monitoring policy for each one (due to differences in the number of tunnels they should have, etc)

[image: Image of gateway_id shown in metric explorer]

I've looked at the outputs from google_compute_ha_vpn_gateway however I appear to be missing this, or it's simply not exposed in this way?

I note it is shown for classic VPN Gateways, exposed as gateway_id but this appears to be missing for the HA VPN gateways.

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation right, you can set the ID yourself: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_ha_vpn_gateway#nested_vpn_interfaces.

Comment: Ah thank you @MarkoE I'll have a look at that, it's weird they've moved it to the interface, but it might work?

Comment: Sadly this isn't what I need, the ID refered to there is simply the numbering of the interfaces, 0, 1, 2, 3. Used for the redundant connections.